# Compiling atk from source

Tags: linux, compilation, configure, glib

I tried to compile atk 2.7.91 from source. Since I am working on an older ubuntu system there are no recent packages for the required glib version. So I just downloaded glib 2.35.8 and did successfully `./configure` and `make` for it (I don't want to install it system-wide so I didn't do `make install`).

Suppose this glib is in `/foobar/glib-2.35.8`. Now I `cd` to `/foobar/atk-2.7.91` and export the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`: `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/foobar/glib-2.35.8:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

Then

`pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0`

tells me:

`2.35.8`

But when I do `./configure` I get the error message:

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.31.2... no
*** Could not run GLIB test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GLIB is incorrectly installed.
configure: error: 
*** GLIB 2.31.2 or better is required. The latest version of
*** GLIB is always available from ftp://ftp.gtk.org/. If GLIB is installed
*** but not in the same location as pkg-config add the location of the file
*** glib-2.0.pc to the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH.
```

`cat config.log |grep glib` gives:

```
configure:12143: checking for GLIB - version >= 2.31.2
configure:12258: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -Wall -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include    -DG_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DATK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES  conftest.c -L/usr/local/lib -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0    >&5
conftest.c:25:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
| #include <glib.h>
|   fclose (fopen ("conf.glibtest", "w"));
|   if ((glib_major_version != 2) ||
|       (glib_minor_version != 35) ||
|       (glib_micro_version != 8))
|       printf("\n*** 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned %d.%d.%d, but GLIB (%d.%d.%d)\n",
|              glib_major_version, glib_minor_version, glib_micro_version);
|       printf ("*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error\n");
|   else if ((glib_major_version != GLIB_MAJOR_VERSION) ||
|      (glib_minor_version != GLIB_MINOR_VERSION) ||
|            (glib_micro_version != GLIB_MICRO_VERSION))
|       printf("*** GLIB header files (version %d.%d.%d) do not match\n",
|        GLIB_MAJOR_VERSION, GLIB_MINOR_VERSION, GLIB_MICRO_VERSION);
|        glib_major_version, glib_minor_version, glib_micro_version);
|       if ((glib_major_version > major) ||
|         ((glib_major_version == major) && (glib_minor_version > minor)) ||
|         ((glib_major_version == major) && (glib_minor_version == minor) && (glib_micro_version >= micro)))
|         printf("\n*** An old version of GLIB (%u.%u.%u) was found.\n",
|                glib_major_version, glib_minor_version, glib_micro_version);
|         printf("*** You need a version of GLIB newer than %u.%u.%u. The latest version of\n",
|         printf("*** GLIB is always available from ftp://ftp.gtk.org.\n");
|         printf("*** of GLIB, but you can also set the PKG_CONFIG environment to point to the\n");
configure:12304: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -Wall -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include    -DG_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DATK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES  conftest.c  -L/usr/local/lib -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0   >&5
conftest.c:25:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
| #include <glib.h>
|  return ((glib_major_version) || (glib_minor_version) || (glib_micro_version));
*** GLIB 2.31.2 or better is required. The latest version of
*** GLIB is always available from ftp://ftp.gtk.org/. If GLIB is installed
*** glib-2.0.pc to the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH.
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=/foobar/glib-2.35.8/:
GLIB_CFLAGS=''
GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES=''
GLIB_GENMARSHAL=''
GLIB_LIBS=''
GLIB_MKENUMS=''
GLIB_PACKAGES='gobject-2.0'
GLIB_REQUIRED_VERSION='2.31.2'
PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/foobar/glib-2.35.8/:'
```

Any idea what's wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: you should look here and adjust your path glib.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the glib somewhere, you can't just point ATK at the Glib build directory. You can install it somewhere private like ~/install by

`./configure --prefix=/home/<username>/install`

(configure doesn't like ~ IIRC)

Comment: Thanks. After doing this I did `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/<username>/install/glib/lib/pkgconfig/` and also  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/<username>/build/glib/lib` and it worked. But I don't really understand, why for example `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/<username>/install/glib/lib/` doesn't work. Do you have any reference for a good resource to learn those things?

Answer (score 3):

### SHORT ANSWER

As (almost) always the Manual is your friend. Try taking a look at `man pkg-config` you'll see it's the `.pc` files that pkg-config needs to perform it's job. `glib-2.0.pc` in your case. Unfortunately it's not as easy as just pointing to the location, where it is stored, but leave that for the long answer at the end and take a look at the manual page for a while first.

> pkg-config  retrieves  information about packages  from special
>   metadata files. These files are named after the package, and  has a
>   .pc extension.  On most systems, pkg-config looks in and for these 
>   files.  It will additionally look in the colon-separated (on Windows,
>   semicolon-separated) list of directories specified by the
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.
>
> The  package  name  specified  on  the pkg-config command line is
>   defined to be the name of the metadata file, minus the .pc extension. 
>   If a library can install multiple versions simultaneously, it must
>   give each version its own  name  (for  example,  GTK  1.2 might have
>   the package name "gtk+" while GTK 2.0 has "gtk+-2.0").

I hope you found the funny

> On most systems, pkg-config looks in and for these files

line. The result may differ on yours system, but on mine it actually displays it that way, which is most probably a bug.

Nevertheless you can find out the compiled in standard directories by running
`pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` which for example prints

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/i486-linux-gnu:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig/i486-linux-gnu:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

on my system.

### LONG ANSWER

To get back to your original question, taking a look at an example `.pc` file might best explain why your first effort was in vain.
As an example here the contents of the `glib-2.0.pc` file on my system:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

glib_genmarshal=glib-genmarshal
gobject_query=gobject-query
glib_mkenums=glib-mkenums

Name: GLib
Description: C Utility Library
Version: 2.24.2
Libs: -L${libdir} -lglib-2.0 
Libs.private: 
Cflags: -I${includedir}/glib-2.0 -I${libdir}/glib-2.0/include
```

As you will hopefully see the whole pathes are all hardwired. Don't get confused by `${libdir}` ... and the like. Taking a closer look you will see they are all constructed from `prefix=/usr` in the first line.

The reason trying to just point PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the build directory of your glib won't work as the path specified in the `.pc` ist the installation directory and not the location of your build directory.

That's why your `pkg-config --modversion` test ran just fine: The `.pc` file was indeed found and contained the given information, but the compilation failed: the `.pc` file was found as in the first case, but the pathes given in the `.pc` file were simply wrong.

No one can forbid you to just change the directories given in the `.pc` to any path you like, so in fact you could make the fresh built library work in its build directory by manually fixing the pathes given in the `.pc` file.
At least if the library itself doesn't contain any hardwired pathes, but that would only be a problem at runtime not while linking.

To even solve the last puzzle - how the the hell could the `.pc` file know where it is going to be installed to give the right prefix?
Just take a look at your source directory.
Acompanying your `glib-2.0.pc` file you'll find a file called `glib-2.0.pc.in` there, with content like that given below:

```
prefix=@prefix@
exec_prefix=@exec_prefix@
libdir=@libdir@
includedir=@includedir@

glib_genmarshal=glib-genmarshal
gobject_query=gobject-query
glib_mkenums=glib-mkenums

Name: GLib
Description: C Utility Library
Version: @VERSION@
Requires.private: @PCRE_REQUIRES@
Libs: -L${libdir} -lglib-2.0 @INTLLIBS@
Libs.private: @G_THREAD_LIBS@ @G_LIBS_EXTRA@ @PCRE_LIBS@ @INTLLIBS@ @ICONV_LIBS@
Cflags: -I${includedir}/glib-2.0 -I${libdir}/glib-2.0/include @GLIB_EXTRA_CFLAGS@
```

The whole `@....@` placeholders where filled in at configure time, when you were running `configure`. i.e. `@prefix@` was filled with the argument given as `--prefix=` on the command line, while others like `@NTLLIBS@` were filled with parameters detected by the configure script.